# Installed package not being found by Spark exectuors

Tags: python, pyspark, import, module

I have the `pycountry` package install for python3.6. I launch the PySpark shell using the following command:

```
pyspark --driver-memory 50g --executor-memory 10g --conf "spark.pyspark.python=/usr/bin/python3.6" --conf "spark.pyspark.driver.python=/usr/bin/python3.6"
```

I have this UDF defined:

```
@F.udf
def get_phone_number_country_iso(phone_number):
    try:
        phone_number_country = phone_number_geocoder.country_name_for_number(
            phone_number_parse("+" + phone_number), lang="en"
        )
        phone_number_country_iso = pycountry.countries.search_fuzzy(
            phone_number_country
        )[0].alpha_2
        return phone_number_country_iso
    except:
        return None
```

And I call it like this:

```
phone_number_vertices = customer_phone_numbers_extract.select("phone_number").distinct()
phone_number_vertices = phone_number_vertices.withColumn(
    "country", get_phone_number_country_iso("phone_number")
)
```

However, I get the following in the stacktrace:

```
 File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1611641681592_0049/container_1611641681592_0049_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 361, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_udfs(pickleSer, infile, eval_type)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1611641681592_0049/container_1611641681592_0049_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 236, in read_udfs
    arg_offsets, udf = read_single_udf(pickleSer, infile, eval_type, runner_conf)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1611641681592_0049/container_1611641681592_0049_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 163, in read_single_udf
    f, return_type = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1611641681592_0049/container_1611641681592_0049_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 64, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1611641681592_0049/container_1611641681592_0049_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1611641681592_0049/container_1611641681592_0049_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 577, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1611641681592_0049/container_1611641681592_0049_01_000002/pyspark.zip/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 875, in subimport
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycountry'

        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:452)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:406)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage8.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:836)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I test the pycountry package in the PySpark shell outside of the UDF, it works fine. Why can't the executors find the installed package?

Comment: did you install the package on the executor's python?

Comment: No, I didn't even know that had to be done! Thank, will look into it

Answer (score 0):

You can add external python packages using `--py-files` option:

1. **Install dependencies into a specific directory:**

```sh
pip install pycountry -t ./libs # same for other packages

# or from a requirements.txt file:
pip install -r requirements.txt  -t ./libs
```

2. **Create a zip archive of the dependencies:**

```sh
cd ./libs && zip -r ../libs.zip .
```

3. **Use `--py-files` to add the created archive:**

```sh
pyspark --py-files /path/to/libs.zip
```

Or add in the code using `sc.addPyFile()`:

```py
sc.addPyFile("/path/to/libs.zip")
```

However, this option won't work all the time as there are some packages that use some native libraries and can't be portable across 2 different environments (eg. you installed the package on local and you use it in EMR/Dataproc cluster). In this case, install the package in all the nodes.